# Using VS2015 Express, deleted VS2013 Community, can't run "MSVCP120d.dll missing"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll

As per the title. I had VS2013 Community installed, I had started a project on that and then moved on the VS2015 Express and converted the project. Recently I needed extra space on my machine so I deleted 2013C using Add or Remove Programs, but now my code gives an exception immediately on running, saying "The program can't start because the MSVCP120D.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem." I went and installed the VS2013 redist, and the problem still persists. Is it possible to solve this without reinstalling the entirety of VS2013?

The odd thing is, the DLL it's looking for is a debug DLL, and I'm running the .code in release mode, and I did check, the runtime library is /MT not /MTd

The .dll doesn't exist in my /Windows/System32 folder despite me having installed the redist.

Edit: I found a copy of the dll and installed it but not the code just doesn't run, it doesn't give the same exception but it just says failed to start.

Comment: Have you tried a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Yes I have, unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: Make sure all of the dependencies of your application were built with VS2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The d library is not "redistributable" and only exists in the development environment.

My recommendation is to use the depends tool (drag executable into depends.exe and it shows the dll dependency), which is part of the windows kits SDK to open your executable.

That should highlight a DLL which was built with the earlier 120d configuration, and can be re-built.

I think the VS 2013 is a side-by-side assembly, and has very strange locations (windows\system32\winsxs).

Comment: Thanks, this fixed it. One of the libraries I was using was indeed built with VS2013.